# How do I remove a file from /etc/environment?

Tags: command-line

Whenever I type `sudo vim /etc/environment` into the terminal I see a file that I don't want on the path. I am not sure how to remove it and have not been able to find any particularly clear guides on how to do so.
I have tried editing bash.rc but the file doesn't show up there at all so I'm not sure where it's even coming from.

Is there a simple way to edit this?

thanks

Comment: Stay away from editing system files unless you have good reasons. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Use `sudo nano /etc/environment`. It will be more clear to you how to edit ;-)